# Querying Serialized Properties isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4jrb

I want querying for a serialized field or property in neo4jrb, but isn't working.

i have a serialized property of type array, something like that:

```
Class Thing
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :coordinates, default: [0,0]

  serialize :coordinates, type: Array
end
```

I want querying

```
Thing.where(coordinates: [1,2])
```

and that returns [ ], but i have a Thing with [1,2] coordinates.

which is the way for asking that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

MATCH( result: 'Thing' )
WHERE (result.coordinates = [1, 2] )
RETURN result

Comment: Yes!!

This workss

I tryed 

`Thing.as(:cosita).where("cosita.coordinates = [1,2]")` and it worked